# How to insert data to mongo synchronously (Nodejs, Express)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, synchronous

I have a problem with inserting data to mongo db using node(express)

My code looks like this:

```
router.get('/data/:section/:sort', function(req, res, next) {
//Deleting old data always before writing new
//Image.remove().exec();
var section = req.params.section;
var sort = req.params.sort;
//Link to Igmur API
var url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/'+section+'/'+sort+'/1'; //1 at the end is used to get more than 60 images(gives only 60 without it)
    request.get({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Client-Id XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    }}, function(e, r, body){
var metadata = JSON.parse(body);
for(var i = 0; i<100; i++){
        var image = new Image(metadata.data[i])
        image.save(function(err, result){
        });
};res.render('index', { title: 'SearchAPI' });});});
```

The problem is that I get only about 20 objects inserted instead of 100 as u can see in the loop.
All because node just jump forward before the save method is completely done.
How can I fix this? Thank you in advance

Comment: btw everything is fine with standalone app. But in express it's goes wrong

Comment: async/await would do the trick in nowadays js :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a promise library such as [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

What you basically need to do is wait for all your `save` methods to complete. Use the `Q.all` method which waits for everything to be executed.

```
var Q = require('q');

var promiseArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i<100; i++){
        var imgDefer = Q.defer();
        var image = new Image(metadata.data[i])
        image.save(function(err, result){
             if(err)imgDefer.reject(err);
             else imgDefer.resolve()
        });
       promiseArr.push(imgDefer);
}
Q.all(promiseArr).then (function (){
    res.render('index', { title: 'SearchAPI' });
})
```

Comment: I don't know why but it still gives me only 20 rows inserted :S But i know that input data has 650 rows and i only need 100 of them

Comment: Newermind I'm just an idiot xD Was checking all inserts using mongo cmd, so it gave me only first 20 and then "type it for more" I didn't notice :D Thanx your code works! But I think mine was working as well xD

Comment: Yours would have worked, but the response was thrown much much earlier than it should have. If your response needed something from the images, then you would have had issues.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the database again and again is a wrong practice it's better if you use `create` and pass everything at once. Have a look at the snippet below. Hope it helps.

```
router.get('/data/:section/:sort', function(req, res, next) {
  //Deleting old data always before writing new
  //Image.remove().exec();
  var section = req.params.section;
  var sort = req.params.sort;
  //Link to Igmur API
  var url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/'+section+'/'+sort+'/1'; //1 at the end is used to get more than 60 images(gives only 60 without it)
  request.get({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Client-Id XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  }}, function(e, r, body){
    var metadata = JSON.parse(body);

    Image.create(metadata.data,(err, result)=>{
      //do operations here
      res.render('index', { title: 'SearchAPI' });
    })

    /* WRONG PRACTICE */
    // for(var i = 0; i<100; i++){
    //   var image = new Image(metadata.data[i])
    //   image.save(function(err, result){

    //   });
    // };

  });
});
```