# insertMany inside setTimeout and for loop with async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm trying to write the following code and make it work synchronously, but the only problem that it works correctly with `console.log`, which prints me every item in array with delay in 1 second, but don't work with the following structure:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        1.http request via rp or request.get (I receive a huge data array)
        2. .map results 
        3.insert to Mongo via mongoose 
     }
}
```

as for now I have the following code inside:

```
request.get({url: array[i].url}), function (error, body) {
    body.map(element => {
        //do stuff, it works fine
     });
     collection.insertMany(body, function (err, docs) {
         //#justloggerthings
     }
```

Or I have almost the same version with `rp` instead of `request.get`
By default I have `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;`

Why this cause a problem? Because `body.length` is very huge dataset which eat a lot of RAM. (Now imagine 20+ arrays with `insertMany`)

So Mongo trying to `insertMany` all responses from request at once (when they ready, w/o 1000s delay). Actually that's why I choose `request` instead of `rp` (`request-promise`) but it seems look async too. So should I choose another http get module from `npm` and switch to it. And not to worry about it?

Or should I wrap this operations to promise || made an async function and recall it inside loop every time (1000s for example) when I it's correctly finished. In this case, the only thing which I found actual on StackOverflow is:

[How to insert data to mongo synchronously (Nodejs, Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191639/how-to-insert-data-to-mongo-synchronously-nodejs-express)

Bit it's a bit outdated. So any ideas?

Comment: If you dont want to insert all the responses at once, then dont use insertMany.
Loop over responses and insert one by one.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that `.create` 50'000+ elements better than use `.insertMany(array)`. My responses from `request` isn't a simple document, it's huge array with documents.

[*TL:DR: I need to insert 10+ this arrays (`body`) one-by-one instead of inserting them all-at-once. That's why I'm using `for` and `setTimeout` Logic in this case is simple: request via url dataset `body` (it's an array) and then insert it to Mongo, because if I insert all them at once it require a lot of RAM (like I mentioned before)*]

Comment: If you want to do it sequentially, use `await` in a loop, not `map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual code that solve my problem is:

```
async function test (name, url, lastModified) {
    try {
        const response = await rp({uri: url, json: true});
        response.map(async (element) => {
            if (element.buyout > 0) {
                element.price = (element.buyout / element.quantity);
            }
            element.lastModified = lastModified
        });
        return collection.insertMany(response);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}

async function addAsync() {
    const z = await test();
    console.log(z);
}

addAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i dont have your actual code so i will write in pseudo code what you can do.

```
const chunkArray = (array, chunkSize) => {
    let i,j,chunks = [];
    for (i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i += chunkSize) {
        chunks.push(array.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
    }
    return chunks;
}

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let bigArray = await request('your data url');
    // do some mapping or whatever
    // then break your large array into smaller chunks
    let chunks = chunkArray(bigArray, 10);
    let j;
    for (j = 0; j < chunks.length; j++) {
        await collection.insertMany(chunks[j]);
    }

}
```